# Increase Scroll Speed Kensington Trackball

Tags: mouse, xinput

I have a [Kensington Expert Mouse Trackball](https://www.kensington.com/p/products/electronic-control-solutions/trackball-products/expert-mouse-wireless-trackball-1/) I am using on Ubuntu. It was a 'plug-and-play' set up so everything is working as expected. Although, I did notice the scroll speed using the scroll ring is a little slow for my liking.

I looked into the xinput command and that looks simple enough, but my question is: Which one of these commands do I need to adjust to increase the speed of the scroll ring?

```
$ xinput list-props 10
Device 'Kensington Expert Wireless TB Mouse':
    Device Enabled (187):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (189): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (322):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (323):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (324):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (325):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (326):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (327): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (328): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (329):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (330):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (331): 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (332): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (333):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (334):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (335):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (336): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (337): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (307): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (308):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (309):    0, 0
    Device Node (310):  "/dev/input/event7"
    Device Product ID (311):    1149, 32792
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (338):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (339):   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an alternative slotion to increase the scroll speed.

Step 1. Install the package lm wheel using the command

```
sudo apt-get install imwheel
```

Step 2. Download a bash script from [here.](http://www.nicknorton.net/mousewheel.sh)
Save the script in your home folder. Make it executable. Execute the script to open a window that helps to change your scroll speed.

Comment: this is great, thank you!

Comment: +1 this works great.  For anyone else wondering, changing the value in the window does *not* take effect immediately, you need to "Apply", play around, and try again if it's not to your liking.  The default setting is "1" and even "3" is plenty fast for me.